# Why in text mode can't open frame in the another monitor?

Tags: frames

Linux Mint 21

Emacs 27.1

On my PC are plugging 3 monitors.

So when I run Emacs in GUI mode and then run command M`-x make-frame-on-monitor`

I get the next  result:

[image]

I select desire monitor and Emacs open new frame in selected monitor.

Nice.

Now I run Emacs in text mode like this: `emacs -nw` and then run command M`-x make-frame-on-monitor`, I get the next result:

[image]

As you can see I can't select another monitor. How I can do this in text mode?

Comment: n.b. You can open new frames from a terminal frame, but only one of them can be displayed in the terminal at a time.  You can see in the mode line which frame is currently being displayed (F1, F2, etc).

Comment: @phils whoa! you taught me something, you should make that comment into a complete answer (I guess you have to add that "monitors" and "displays" don't make sense as a concept in terminal, but that frames still do)

Answer (score 2):

You’re running Emacs inside of a terminal emulator. Historical terminals only ever had one monitor, and so terminal emulators only provide a single window to the applications running inside them. Thus there is no way for Emacs to do it.

The closest you can get is to run `M-x server-start`, then open another copy of the terminal emulator and run `emacsclient` in it. This is a lot more complicated than merely opening a new frame in the Emacs GUI, but it has a similar effect.

Comment: Another option is `make-frame-on-display`, but then you need to move the frame to the right monitor,